# How to add BlockComment extension for Xcode 11?

Tags: macos, xcode, plugins

I'm new at the excode editor. I want to be able to add block comments (`/* 
 */`), so I found an [extension](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/blockcomment-for-xcode/id1246672247?mt=12).

But I can't seem to be able to add it to xcode.

Everything leads me to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Extensions` but there's nothing there!

[image]

Elsewhere, apparently `BlockComment` should be in the `Key Binding` section, but it isn't.

Some other research says that I should see `BlockComment` in the `editor` drop-down menu and that's not there.

Can this be done?

Comment: Have you enabled it under System Preferences -> Extensions -> Xcode Source Editor ? Not in Xcode, but in the general system preferences app?

Comment: @Lizzan damn that was the problem, I thought preferences in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link to app support at the bottom of the app store page you linked. That should be a go-to place always.

https://github.com/superk589/BlockComment

> #### from mac App Store
>
> 1. Run the application at lease once, then close it.
> 2. Go to System Preferences -> Extensions -> Xcode Source Editor and enable this extension
> 3. Reopen Xcode and you can find this extension from Xcode menu.